# How do I add System.Environment if it isn't a part of my library?

Tags: c#

I need to add a new line to some information I'm formatting. After a quick google search I see `System.Environment.NewLine` would do exactly what I need it to however after trying to call that command it doesn't show as available.

I went up to the top of the page to try and add it by indicating `using System.Environment` however it didn't pull up from the list of available classes. I'm guessing I have a limited library, What can I do to add it?

Comment: what are framework you targeting?

Comment: what platform? what version of VS?

Comment: what actually happens? and how do you call it?

Comment: `Environment` is a class in the System namespace.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Communit 2015 version 14.0.24720.00 update 1.

Comment: This doesn't directly solve your problem, but [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) returns: "A string containing `"\r\n"` for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing `"\n"` for Unix platforms."

Answer (score 2):

`Environment` is a class in `mscorlib.dll`, which is referenced by all .NET applications.

You can access it in different ways:

1. Add `using System;` then call `Environment.NewLine`
2. Call `System.Environment.NewLine`

Comment: Actually that class is in `mscorlib.dll` not `System.dll`

Comment: Yup, you are right. Edited my answer. I believe mscorlib is referenced by all .net apps so no additional references should be required (although System is also referenced by default)

Answer (score 0):

`Environment` is a class, not a namespace. You don't reference it in a `using` statement.  If you have `System` in your `using` block you should be able to access `Environment.NewLine` in your code.

In C# 6 you can reference a static class in your using block to avoid repeating it in code:

```
using static System.Environment;

...

Console.Write(NewLine);
```

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sorry newb mistake. I see it now thank you for your help